# MVC passing data to view and looping

Tags: for-loop, asp.net-mvc-4, view, action, models

I am terribly confused with MVC.

I don't have any code to show because i don't know how to do it.

I have an object

```
public class Name()
{
  String name="balh"
  String something="blah blah"
  //this object works fine and doesn't look like this it has the appropriate get;set;
  //use this as just an example
  //please disregard this format
}
```

Now i have a

```
List<Name> list;//this just holds all of my objects
```

I need them to be passed to the View

I keep seeing something about models but i don't see it declared anywhere

How do i loop in the view to create something like this

```
<div> object1 string</div>
<div> object2 string</div>
<div> object3 string</div>
<div> object4 string</div>
<div> object5 string</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view would look like this, assuming you use your list as the model:

```
@model List<Name>

@foreach(var item in Model) {
  <div> @item.name @item.something</div>
}
```

So your controller action method might be:

```
public ViewResult Index() {
  // Somehow build list which is List<Name>
  return View(list);
}
```

EDIT:  You seem very new, so I recommend trying this tutorial:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: You are sooo amazing... I wish so much blessing and you have the best 2013!!ever!!!

Comment: @Lpc_dark NP.  I updated my answer with a link to a tutorial that should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take an example.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<MyViewModel> model = new List<MyViewModel>();
        model.Add(new MyViewModel { Name = "some name", Something = "something" });
        model.Add(new MyViewModel { Name = "some other name", Something = "something else" });
        return View(mdoel);
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Something</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (vat item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Something</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
  @foreach (vat item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.Something</td>
        </tr>
    }
```